# NGINX и микросервисы | Проверка разрешений API токена

Tags: nginx, микросервисы, сервисы

Разрабатываю микросервисы, возникла проблема проверки разрешений к контенту, например:

Есть 3 микосервиса:

```
/auth - авторизация
/lessons - расписание
/messages - сообщения
```

В бд сохранены ключи API к которым привязаны разрешения, nginx настроен так, что когда клиент делает запрос к /lessons или /messages, nginx делает `auth_request /auth/scopes` и оттуда сохраняет хедер Scopes, где перечислены разрешения которые вернул микросервис авторизации.

Далее запрос проксируется но уже с хедером Scopes. И уже сам микросервис парсит хедер, проверяет, можно ли давать информацию или нет.

Как считаете, этот способ хороший, есть ли лучше?

Comment: Можно избавиться от auth_request ценой невозможности мгновенно отозвать действующие разрешения. См. JWT. А лучше это или хуже зависит от ситуации.

Comment: Я не хочу использовать JWT, так как их нельзя будет отозвать, если что-то пойдет не по плану, этот способ мне нужен для постоянных токенов, которые будут назначены ботам, или разработчикам, в этом все дело, да и вопрос был совсем про другое, является ли такой способ хорошим..

Comment: Но чисто, как на ваш взгяд это использовать, каждый сервис сам проверяет скопы, если нету, то 403

Comment: Нормальный способ. А кто же ещё кроме сервиса лучше знает какие скоупы ему подходят?